# Doctrine MongoDB geoNear

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I am trying to see how to do geoNear command without rewriting doctrine-mongodb project. I have looked through Expr.php and Builder.php files and I found no references to geoNear command, how can I get this functionality in my Doctrine MongoDB ODM ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The lastes version of DoctrineODM has the `geoNear` method: [See the code](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php#L593)

However, bear in mind that `geoNear` is truly an hack made for Foursquare by the MongoDB team. It returns only the first 100 results ordered by distance (and you can't paginate)

Use **$near** instead: [$near Doc for Mongo 2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/near/)

```
$query->field('coordinates')
      ->equals(array('$near' => array($lat, $lon) 
                   , '$maxDistance' => $maxDistanceKm / 111));
```

---

Warning: **$near** changed in Mongo 2.4, now it return only the first 100 items too: [$near Doc for Mongo 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/)

---

If you don't need to sort by distance, use `$geoWithin` (or `$within` in Mongo 2.2), then you can sort by other fields and paginate:

```
$query->field('coordinates')
       ->equals(array('$within' => array('$center' => array(array($lat, $lon)
                                        , $maxDistanceKm / 111) ) ));
```

Comment: So you cannot paginate (limit) with `$near`?

Comment: Last time I've checked: no. With newer Mongo use the aggregate framework, however consider that many operations are done in memory, and so limited to 16Mb of results

Answer (score 0):

How old is your library version ?

There is an implementation of geoNear command available on [Doctrine MongoDb mappers's trunk](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb), `$qb->near(array($x, $y))`. But have tested it just very quickly, i can't tell you how good it works in an extensive usage.